# Only continue Automator script when Applescript is done

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm coding a small Automator script with an Applescript in it.
The Applescript runs a shell script that downloads some images to a specified folder.
The next step in the Automator script makes a PDF from those images.
Small problem, the creation of the PDF already starts before the downloading of the images is done, so i get an empty PDF file.
how can i let Automator wait until the Applescript is done downloading before it gets to the next step?

Comment: Can you post your AppleScript code? Without it, it's very hard to guess a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

What shell command(s) are you using to do the download? curl? One way to do this would be to add something to the shell script after each download, like:

```
curl http://whatever/Your/Url/is/file1.xxx;echo ''>file1.deleteme
```

then make sure your applescript only starts the pdf part after it finds the file1.deleteme file and deletes it. When I do this with curl, it will not make that empty file until it is done downloading.

the AS part could start with something like (danger, not tested):

```
--within outer loop for each file...
tell application "Finder"
 repeat until exists (pathToDeleteMeFile)--this is built using basename + "deleteme"
  delay 1--one second delay
 end repeat
end tell
--do pdf stuff here for that (each) file
```

or, if you prefer (or if this makes more sense depending on what your code looks like:

do the shell script for *all* files, create a more generic deleteme file after they are *all* done, *then* do the pdf stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Automator *does* wait until Run Script actions are done.  The problem, at a guess without seeing your code, is that your AppleScript is  using some sort of asynchronous download method -- telling Safari, perhaps? -- so the script finishes before the download is actually done.  Using a synchronous method, such as the above suggestion of `curl`(1), should fix things.

By the way, using a Run Script action to call `do shell script` is a bit silly; you could just use Run Shell Script instead.